# Adding Python 2 kernel to Ipython

Tags: python, linux, ipython

I have Jupyter Notebook installed on Ubuntu. Python 2 and 3 run OK on the terminal but only Python 3 shows up on IPython. I am trying to get both kernels (2 and 3) up on IPython.

I've tried to manually install ipykernel from https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel which was successful but still can't get Python 2 kernel to show up. I also tried:

```
> sudo ipython2 kernelspec install-self
```

And got the error: `ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size`

Next, i tried:

```
python2 -m pip install --upgrade ipykernel 
python2 -m ipykernel install
```

The second line returned an error:

```
/usr/bin/python2: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size; 'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I guess the challenge is with the module named *shutil_get_terminal_size*. Please, kindly advise on how I can fix this. I read this post: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9416 but can't make much sense of it.

Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly an answer,  but why not use separate virtual environments for Python 2 and Python 3? This is what I do.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue and found that a `backports` package was installed in both the Python 2.7 system site directory *and* the user site directory.  Furthermore, the `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size` package was only in the system site directory:

```
$ ls -l $(find / -name 'backports' 2>/dev/null)
/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 88 Aug  4 16:04 configparser

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  75 Aug  4 17:58 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 267 Aug  4 17:58 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 128 Aug  4 17:58 shutil_get_terminal_size
```

When Python executes an `import` statement, it looks in the user site directory first, and then looks in the system site directory.  Since the `shutil_get_terminal_size` package is not in the `backports` package in the user site directory, that import will always fail.  Here's what the import error looks like in its minimal form:

```
$ echo "from backports.shutil_get_terminal_size import get_terminal_size; \
        print(get_terminal_size())" | python2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size
```

Adding the `-s` option on the python command line tells Python to **not** use the user site directory, and the import command succeeds:

```
$ echo "from backports.shutil_get_terminal_size import get_terminal_size; \
        print(get_terminal_size())" | python2 -s
terminal_size(columns=319, lines=104)
```

The `install` command also succeeds when the `-s` option is added to the python command line:

```
$ python2 -s -m ipykernel install
Installed kernelspec python2 in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
```

How the `backports` package got into the user site directory in the first place is still a mystery.